# Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ if $x=\frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x)=0$ if not. Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{n}$ if $x=\frac{1}{n}$ and $f(x)=0$ if not. Show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$. I would like to have a feedback on my proof and to know if it holds.

My attempt is to pass by Darboux upper and lower sums.

To show that $f$ is Riemann integrable, we have to show the following:$\forall \epsilon>0$ $\exists$ a partition $\sigma$: $\overline{S}_{\sigma}(f)<\underline{S}_{\sigma}(f)+\epsilon$.

We remark that $\underline{S}_{\sigma}(f)$ is always equal to $0$, whatever the partition (by density of rational and irrational numbers). So, we need to show that $\forall \epsilon>0 \ \exists$ a partition $\sigma$: $\overline{S}_{\sigma}(f)<\epsilon$. Let $0<\epsilon<1$ and consider the following intervals: $[0,\epsilon/2]$ and $(\epsilon/2,1]$. We remark that on the second interval there is clearly a finite number of discontinuities. Suppose $N$ such that $\frac{1}{N}>\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ (so $\frac{1}{N}\in (\epsilon/2,1]$). We see as well that the number of numbers of the form $1/n$ on the interval $(\epsilon/2,1]$ is at most $\frac{2}{\epsilon}$. So, to "simplify" the sum we can fix the distance between these numbers as $\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}$, which is possible (we can check that $\frac{1}{N-1}-\frac{1}{n}>\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}$). Thus,

$\overline{S}_{\sigma}(f)=M_i(x_{i+1}-x_i)=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{2}{\epsilon}\cdot\frac{\epsilon^2}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\frac{\epsilon}{n}\le \epsilon \ \forall n\in\mathbf{N}^*$

Therefore, $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4038160/show-that-f-is-riemann-integrable

Comment: @Peter O. Yes, it is nearly the same question (to make it the same I could simply bound  $\frac{1}{n}$ by $1$) but here I created another subdivision (not the same as in the post), so I would like to know if it holds.

Comment: Could anyone give a feedback, please?